# Samsung default browser or any default browser in android is not supporting back camera

Tags: javascript, android, browser

Below is my code, I am making qr code scanner(for Mobile device) using the below plugin

https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR

which supports almost Chrome, Mozilla FireFox, Opera, MS EDGE in Mobile devices, but I am trying to achieve in all latest devices default browsers(android- mostly Samsung devices) also its working but instead of taking rear camera(back camera) its taking front camera (user facing) for that I have written a code as per developers Mozilla group

```
{ facingMode: { exact: "environment" } }
```

here is my code

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }).then(function(stream) {
                  video.srcObject = stream;
                  video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
                  video.play();
                  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
                  localStream = stream;
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                      /* handle the error */
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution to my issue you need to use navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices and get the device id and assign it getUserMedia, but the may rise browser compability issue, I have written a code for that too, using a condition

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
                .then(function(devices) {

                var videoDevices = [0,0];
                var videoDeviceIndex = 0;
                devices.forEach(function(device) {
                                        if(device.kind == "videoinput") { 
                                            videoDevices[videoDeviceIndex++] =  device.deviceId;  
                                        }
                 });

                var isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);
                var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
                            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") !== -1){
                                console.log("Firefox")
                                var constraints =  {facingMode: videoDevices[1] };
                            } else if(isSafari && iOS){
                                console.log("Safari")
                                var constraints =  { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } };
                            } else {
                                console.log("other browser")
                                var constraints =  {deviceId: {  exact: videoDevices[1]  }  }
                            }
                                return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: constraints });

                              }).then(function(stream) {
                                  video.srcObject = stream;
                                  video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); 
                                  video.play();

                                })
                                .catch(function(err) {
                                   //use this to display the error 
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use facingMode to choose "user" or "environment" for front or back camera respectively.

Use

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } },
successCallback, errorCallback);
```

as above you are already using, try to make call like below by removing `exact`:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({video: { facingMode: "environment" } },
successCallback, errorCallback);
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: I have tried both codes but still it takes the front camera in default browsers... so I am looking for a code which can force to chose only rear camera (back camera)

Comment: @KundanSIngh are you facing this issue **only on** Samsung devices? Have you verified on any Nexus device? What is OS version?

Comment: Android OS version is from 4.3 to 8.1, I am yet to check in Nexus!

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4 and Nexus 5 still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

should this (~line 18):

```
var constraints =  {facingMode: videoDevices[1] };
```

be

```
var constraints =  {deviceID: {exact: videoDevices[1]} };
```

ps: verified that Samsung S4 still has the issue